# How to identify the reports type from Google Analytics Reporting API v4 batch request?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Google Analytics Reporting API's [batch request](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) feature is really great. We can request multiple reports in a single HTTP request. But results are returned as an array. How do we get the specific report type from that array?

```
$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( $requests );
$reports = $this->analytics->reports->batchGet( $body )->getReports();
```

Above batch request consists of top countries, top pages reports. But how do I identify the top countries report from the array?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I ended up setting custom prefix for [metric alias](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#Metric) in different requests and then identify the requests based on the prefix.